# I have formated encrypted disk to install new is and now it's not being recognized

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssd, format, disk-encryption

I was a long time Ubuntu user but decided to use that laptop for gaming. So i wanted to install Windows back. I had encrypted main boot Ubuntu drive,and when I formated it, it's no longer being recognized by any partition utility, either Ubuntu's or windows installer's. I truly don't know what to do, thanks.

Comment: Could be the SSD is failing, if it's not recognized at all. Give DiskGenius, a free Windows app, a try - remove all partitions,, recreate desired partitions from free space, and format each appropriately. Of course, all data will be lost.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about SSD failure! I don't think I can try that,it's just not recognized by any tool

Comment: You might try booting [hirens](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) and seeing what you can see from there.